# Get Query from one Dockerized Go service to other Dockerized Go Services

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I have some services built in Go and I ma deploying them using docker-compose.

I have also linked the services, but now if I do a GET request from one application to other I get  **unsupported protocol scheme**. This is because I am using the service name in the URL without specifying any protocol. Linking and querying works fine with mongoDB but not with other services.

Go service1 File

```
url :="service2/get" // this is not working 
response, err := http.Get(url)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("%s", err)
} else {
 //do something
 }
```

Docker-compose

```
  service1:
    container_name: 'service1'
    build: 'service1'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    depends_on:
      - 'service2'
    links:
      - 'service2'
  service2:
    container_name: 'service2'
    build: 'service2'
    ports:
      - '9001:9001'
```

Any suggestion how this can be done?

Comment: You seem to understand the problem, isn't specifying ```url := "http://service2/get" ``` enough to make it work?

Comment: Thanks it worked...I should have tried that in the first place only..I tried all other but not this.. Anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

It worked if we use like this

```
url :="http://service2:9001/get" // this is not working 
response, err := http.Get(url)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("%s", err)
} else {
 //do something
 }
```